# pandas groupby and sort values

Tags: pandas, groupby

I am studying for an exam and encountered this problem from past worksheets:
[image]

This is the data frame called 'contest' with granularity as each submission of question from each contestant in the math contest. The question is

[image]
and the answer is in red. I get why that works, but **why is the 4th choice wrong?** I really can't figure it out - please help.

*please let me know if this is not allowed as a post in this community.

for full description of the problem:

> In this question, we will be looking at the contest dataframe which contains data from a
> math contest in 2019. In the contest, each participant had a total of five questions. The participants submit each question separately and each row of the DataFrame records a particular submission of one of the contestants by some participant. The Timestamp column specifies the
> time a given problem is submitted by a participant; each timestamp is discretized to the minute
> and has been properly converted to a Pandas datetime object with pd.to datetime.
> The Contestant column contains the id-name pair of each participant. The Question
> column contains the question that was submitted. The Correct column tells us if the answer
> given in the submission is correct (1) or not (0). Assume each participant can have several
> submissions for the same problem, but they can only submit one question per minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the participant has answered the question 2 before the question 1, you will lose the information on question one by using .agg("first") in the 4th option